# How to find source of Connection Reset Error

Tags: clojure, iis-6

Where can I go look to find the source of a connection reset error? Here are the details:

I have a Clojure applet that uses `clj-http.client`.

I need to track down what is sending the following error

```
Feb 14, 2013 5:16:04 PM 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) 
caught when processing request: Connection reset
Feb 14, 2013 5:16:04 PM 
org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector execute
INFO: Retrying request
```

We have looked through the server's IIS logs, and cannot find any error indicating a connection reset. We've also looked at the server's Event Logs, and cannot find an error that matches the error I'm getting in the client. As a matter of fact, the IIS logs look OK. I can see my address verification "GET" requests right in the log.

Comment: One option would be to use wireshark to inspect the packets and figure out which part closed the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a guess, though I often get that error message when the web server is configured to respond to the wrong host name. If it is serving for www.example.com/my/service and I open a connection to 1.2.3.4/my/service then it hangs up with "connection reset".

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause or not, but it's an excellent answer. I have two implementations of the server (one interim until it works), and their both referred to by DNS alias. It's possible -- won't know until Tuesday -- that the ASP pages are referencing the wrong server. I'll fix that, if it's the case.